# openerp many2many default disappear

Tags: many-to-many, odoo, default

I have a form which I pass some invoice ids through context by an act_window.
Invoices are set as default in an many2many field (I tried both using a default function and overriding the default_get function), but when I add a record on another one2many field in the same form, the many2many field just get cleared (I suppose it refresh itself) It does not happen with other fields which also had defaults but just with the many2many.

Any ideas?

edit: seems that the many2many field disapearing is not related with being a default or not. It happens everytime a record in the other one2many field is inserted. But at the end of the day, when I save the whole record, the m2m records are not deleted on DB: when I open again the form, here there are again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given my edit above, I can only suppose this is just some bug...